# CSVHelper Parsing Multiple CSVs using Multiple Mappings on each File

Tags: csvhelper

I am trying to read in multiple CSV files and I don't have any understanding of which Classmap is needed until I read the CSV file. I need to also interpret multiple different header names using these mappings. I currently have the following code in my Index. Is there a way to check the first field "csv.GetField(0)" against all the values in each of my 3 mappings for each row and then add that value to one of my class lists to then be added to a database. I currently get an error on my while loop saying one of the three record types is not present in the list because I assume it gets stuck using a single mapping instead of multiple

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
private readonly ClientContext _context;
public IndexModel(ClientContext context)
{
_context = context;
}

```
    [BindProperty]
    public FileUpload fileUpload { get; set; }

    //create new lists for all class data types to add to database
    public List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
    public List<Demographic> demographics = new List<Demographic>();
    public List<ReturnData> returnDatas = new List<ReturnData>();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["SuccessMessage"] = "Upload necessary files (MAX OF 4 FILES)";
    }
    public ActionResult OnPostUpload(FileUpload fileUpload)
    {
        //counter
        int i = 1;

        //type of Record
        RecordType type = RecordType.None;

        //for each file in the form files
        foreach (var file in fileUpload.FormFiles)
        {
            //display filenames
            ViewData[i.ToString()] = file.FileName;
            i++;

            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                MissingFieldFound = null,
                HeaderValidated = null,
                IgnoreBlankLines = true,
                UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = false
            };

            //use streamReader and csvHelper to pull records from file
            using var stream = new MemoryStream();
            using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            using var sreader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(sreader, config))
            {
                string[] headerRow = csv.HeaderRecord;

                //add all context mappings to interpret mutliple different header names
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ClientMap>();
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<DemoMap>();
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<DataMap>();

                //grab records and add them to class lists
                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    clients.Add(csv.GetRecord<Client>());
                    demographics.Add(csv.GetRecord<Demographic>());
                    returnDatas.Add(csv.GetRecord<ReturnData>());
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            _context.Client.Add(client);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        foreach (var demographic in demographics)
        {
            _context.Demographic.Add(demographic);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        foreach (var returnData in returnDatas)
        {
            _context.ReturnData.Add(returnData);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Save database changes
        _context.SaveChanges();

        //Process uploaded files
        ViewData["SuccessMessage"] = fileUpload.FormFiles.Count.ToString() + " file(s) uploaded!";
        var DropDownAndCheckBoxCount = i;
        return Page();
    }
    public class FileUpload
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "File")]
        public List<IFormFile> FormFiles { get; set; } // convert to list
        public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }
    }
}


//Client data mapping
    public sealed class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
{
    public ClientMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("ID", "Id");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName", "First Name");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Name("LastName", "Last Name");
        Map(m => m.DoB).Name("DateOfBirth", "DoB", "Date of Birth");
        Map(m => m.Last4SS).Name("Last 4", "XXX-XX-1234", "Last Four", "Last 4 SS");
    }
}

//enum to reference the different mappings for the csv
public enum RecordType
{
    None = 0,
    ClientType,
    DemographicType,
    ReturnDataType,
    TaxYearType
}

//Demographic data mapping
public sealed class DemoMap : ClassMap<Demographic>
{
    public DemoMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("ID", "Id");
        Map(m => m.TaxYear).Name("Tax Year", "TaxYear");
        Map(m => m.Address).Name("Street Address", "Address");
        Map(m => m.Zip).Name("ZIP", "Zip", "zip", "Postal Code");
        Map(m => m.County).Name("County", "Location");
        Map(m => m.State).Name("State", "ST");
    }
}

//ReturnData data mapping
public sealed class DataMap : ClassMap<ReturnData>
{
    public DataMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("ID", "Id");
        Map(m => m.TaxYear).Name("TaxYear", "Tax Year");
        Map(m => m.FederalReturn).Name("FedReturn", "Federal");
        Map(m => m.TotalRefund).Name("Total Refund", "TotalRefund");
        Map(m => m.EITC).Name("EITC");
        Map(m => m.CTC).Name("CTC");
        Map(m => m.Dependents).Name("dependents");
        Map(m => m.SurveyScore).Name("Questions");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 3 different record types were contained in each row, then what you are doing would work.  You can register all the maps and get a record for each record data that is contained in the row.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var clients = new List<Client>();
    var demographics = new List<Demographic>();

    using (var reader = new StringReader("ClientId,First Name,DemoId,Tax Year\n1,John,4,2021"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ClientMap>();
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<DemoMap>();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            clients.Add(csv.GetRecord<Client>());
            demographics.Add(csv.GetRecord<Demographic>());
        }
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Demographic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TaxYear { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
{
    public ClientMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("ClientId");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName", "First Name");
    }
}

public sealed class DemoMap : ClassMap<Demographic>
{
    public DemoMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("DemoId");
        Map(m => m.TaxYear).Name("TaxYear", "Tax Year");
    }
}
```

However, it sounds like each file only contains one type of record. So you need a way to detect what type of record the file contains and only get that record type. You could start each file with some sort of identifier, such as the number of the record type, and then switch on the types of records you are getting by that identifier.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var clients = new List<Client>();
    var demographics = new List<Demographic>();
    
    var files = new List<string>()
    {
        "1\nId,First Name\n1,Jordan\n2,Jennifer",
        "2\nId,Tax Year\n1,2021\n2,2020"
    };

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        IgnoreBlankLines = true,
        UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = false
    };

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader(file))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
            csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ClientMap>();
            csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<DemoMap>();

            csv.Read();

            switch (csv.GetField<RecordType>(0))
            {
                case RecordType.ClientType:
                    clients.AddRange(csv.GetRecords<Client>().ToList());
                    break;
                case RecordType.DemographicType:
                    demographics.AddRange(csv.GetRecords<Demographic>().ToList());
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unable to determine record type");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Demographic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int TaxYear { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
{
    public ClientMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("ID", "Id");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName", "First Name");
    }
}

public sealed class DemoMap : ClassMap<Demographic>
{
    public DemoMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("ID", "Id");
        Map(m => m.TaxYear).Name("TaxYear", "Tax Year");
    }
}

public enum RecordType
{
    None = 0,
    ClientType,
    DemographicType,
    ReturnDataType,
    TaxYearType
}
```

Comment: I am dealing with IFormFiles from an Upload, how would I account for that instead of using the StringReader you use here?

Comment: The same as you were before. Use `using var sreader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());` instead of `using (var reader = new StringReader(file))`.  I just used `StringReader` to make it easier to have an example that you could quickly test out without having to have the files.